# create an animation using graphics, transform and a timer

Tags: c#, winforms, animation, timer, transform

i try making a point'n'click adventure for a school project, i can do it the way i want with the language i want, but there needs to be one new aspect we didn't discuss in lessons. i chose c# and make a windows forms program.

i wanted to make a soundtrack and play it in the background ingame as the new aspect, but my teacher said that would be too easy and told me to do the animations with transform commands. i barely managed to actually make translatetransform work, now i'm trying to animate it using a timer which updates the panel displaying the images. i tried different ways to do so, this is my last solution:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private float move = 0f;
    private int sizex = 40, sizey = 40;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void gavi_ani_timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        gavi.Update();
        move = move + 10;
    }

    private void gavi_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = gavi.CreateGraphics();
        Pen pen1 = new Pen(Color.Red, 5);
        g.TranslateTransform(move, move);
        g.DrawEllipse(pen1, 0, 0, sizex, sizey);
    }

}
```

what do i have to do to make the circle move?

the circle is not part of the actual game, i'm just trying to make it work.

help is much appreciated, thank you

Comment: First: Replace `Graphics g = gavi.CreateGraphics();` by `Graphics g = e.Graphics;` Do you ever start the Timer?

Comment: Also: the way to use a Pen is to either keep a global Pen or put the local one into a using clause: `using (Pen pen1 = new Pen(Color.Red, 5){g.DrawEllipse(pen1, 0, 0, sizex, sizey); }` This way you don't leak GDI resources..

Comment: The drawing works, it's only the moving and timer which bug me. Also rookie here

Comment: Your code may seem to work but it is still wrong. Also, to make you happy: change   `gavi.Update();`  to `gavi.Invalidate();` Use `Update` when actual Properties of a Control have changed. `move` isn't such a Property.. `Invalidate` will always force a `Paint` event..

Comment: thanks a lot, i couldn't try it anymore yesterday, did today and works like a charm. that really helped me getting on with my entire project and helped me understanding that language more